# Extracting TimeOfDay from DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net

I have a date time picker.  I need to extract only time from it to save to database (DateTime column of my DB)
I am trying to get it through DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay but this gives error:

Value of type 'System.TimeSpan' cannot be converted to 'Date?'.

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for new development, you should be using either separate `date` and `time` columns, or a `datetime2` column, per the [Note here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx). Since you're storing only the time, it would probably be easiest to take this approach.

However, to store only the time portion of the `DateTime` value, you will need a base `Date` plus the `TimeOfDay` value. You can get this by taking `DateTimePicker1.Value` directly or by having a constant `Date` you use as the base. Either way, you can't store a `TimeOfDay` without a corresponding `Date` in a SQL `datetime` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you have datetime column in the database you can save the `DateTimePicker1.Value` but it will contain date part also. When you read the column you can get the time of the datetime by using `TimeOfDay` property

You can save `TimeSpan` if the column data type is `time`(SQL Server 2008 and later)

Comment: That won't have the time, it will set it to midnight.

Answer (score -1):

Why not convert your Date variable to String and
then you could either use `ToShortTimeString()` or `ToString()` in your code
before saving it to your DB, like:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortTimeString()
```

or

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString()
```